# Problem migrating to Jetpack Compose. Trying to run the app from within Android Studio generates a wierd error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I've an application that uses Fragmnent Views with XML resources and I want to migrate it to Compose. Being the app quite big, I decided to temporarily have a mixed environment with Compose working together with the old XML resources, so I created a new Compose fragment and I succeeded to add the standard navigation action to navigate to it. The code builds successfully, but when I try to run the app I get the error of the picture below. It is particularly wierd because this error appears immediately, and not in the build panel, but in a popup dialog. Any hint ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the documentation is not very clear, but in the end I found this:

*"You can also include a ComposeView directly in a fragment if your full screen is built with Compose, which lets you avoid using an XML layout file entirely."*

Being my app a hybrid one with XML navigation graphs, it looks like I need to define an XML resource anyway.

I hoped I cound avoid defining an XML layout, but it seems I need one for a fragment that has an old fashioned Activity as parent.

I'll post an update as soon as I discover something new

UPDATE

Adding an XML layout didn't fix the problem.
In fact the XML layout is not necessary. I don't really understand the cause of that error, but after cleaning a couple of times the project and clearing A.S. cache it disappeared. I succeeded to add a Compose Fragment to an old XML resources style app. The old navigation works without problems. Hope this post will help someone else save the time I have wasted...